# Error on AnyAsync()

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

In my ASP.NET Web API application, I get the following error in one of my actions, at the line below:

```
var dateExists = await _unitOfWork.GetRepository<Booking>().All()
    .AnyAsync(b => b.User.UserName == booking.User.UserName && b.Date == model.Date);
```

Here's the error:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous
>   asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any
>   asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method
>   on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.

But, as you can see, I am using `await`. I'm also using `await` on all the other async operations in the action. Then, what might be the problem?

**Edit:**

Here's my entire action:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("Update")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(BookingEditBindingModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Return a bad request response if the model state is invalid...
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    try
    {
        var booking = await _unitOfWork.GetRepository<Booking>().FindAsync(model.BookingId);
        if (booking == null)
        { 
            return NotFound();
        }

        // Only Admin is allowed to update other users' data...
        if (!User.IsInRole("Admin") && booking.User.UserName != User.Identity.Name)
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }

        // There can only be one entry per date/user.
        if (model.Date != booking.Date)
        {
            var dateExists = await _unitOfWork.GetRepository<Booking>().All()
                .AnyAsync(b => b.User.UserName == booking.User.UserName && b.Date == model.Date);
            if (dateExists)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Date", "Data already exists for this date.");
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
        }

        booking.Date = model.Date;
        // Change other properties...

        await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();

        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return InternalServerError(ex);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I disabled lazy loading, but I still had a problem. It looks like, as other people had guessed, the issue was with `booking.User`, because the `FindAsync()` in the first query does not include the `User`. I replaced the first query with the one below, and the issue was resolved.

```
var booking = await _unitOfWork.GetRepository<Booking>().All()
    .Include(b => b.User)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(b => b.BookingId == model.BookingId);
```

Comment: Can you explain why you downvoted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Does Await Not Appear to Prevent Second Operation on EF Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773533/why-does-await-not-appear-to-prevent-second-operation-on-ef-context)

Comment: The code is far from complete. What other operations are part of the Action?  This could come from forgetting an await elsewhere.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I'll add some more code.

Comment: The also include that `.All()` and tell us if lazy loading could be used. Like in the suggested duplicate, `booking.User` could be the culprit.

Comment: I edited the question to add more code.

Comment: On a side note I strongly recommend you do not create additional wrappers around EF. The type `DbContext` is an implementation of a UoW pattern and the type `DbSet<T>` is an implementation of a Repository pattern. Why re-wrap these types in your own implementation of the same pattern? You are adding nothing of value, just more code and a poor abstraction which results in code that is harder to read, debug, and use.

Comment: @Igor, ok, thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: By the way, I have a similar code in my Post action, but don't have any issues with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to go out on a limb and guess that you have lazy loading enabled. This would cause a call like `booking.User.UserName` to go to the database to retrieve the value and putting that inside of a call like `AnyAsync` could cause the `DbContext` to try to open a second connection to retrieve that value after it already opened one for the `AnyAsync` statement.

The quick fix in this case is to retrieve the user name before the call to `AnyAsync`.

```
var bookingUserName = booking.User.UserName;
var dateExists = await _unitOfWork.GetRepository<Booking>().All()
                .AnyAsync(b => b.User.UserName == bookingUserName && b.Date == model.Date);
```

A better fix would be to retrieve this information in advance in the call where you get the `booking` instance so you do not have to make an additional round trip.

*Personally I always disable lazy loading on my `DbContext` types and use `Include` statements to explicitly specify what I want to be retrieved with any call. This gives me more control over my execution.*

Comment: I disabled lazy loading, and now the error was replaced with this one: ""Non-static method requires a target.". So, it has something to do with the expression. I'll have to move it outside of the query. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Apparently, the problem is the FindAsync() on the first query, because it does not include the User.